# サウンドカードのないマシンでAndroid-x86で音声再生に対応するには?

Tags: android, linux

サウンドカード搭載されていないマシン(VPS、GCE、EC2など)で、
Android-x86を動作させたいのですが、音声再生に失敗して正常に動作しないアプリが多く困っています。
回避策はないでしょうか?

■設定例
VM： VirtualBox 5.2.6 (「オーディオを有効化」をチェック外す)
インストール方法: 一度Debian 9.3で構築後、下記などど実行し、GRUBから起動

```
alien -ci android-x86-6.0-r3.x86_64.rpm
```

上記環境で、

```
cp /android-6.0-r3/system.sfs /tmp/
mkdir /tmp/system-img
cd /tmp/
unsquashfs system.sfs
mount squashfs-root/system.img /tmp/system-img
vi /tmp/system-img/etc/init.sh
mksquashfs system-img system_new.sfs
cp system_new.sfs /android-6.0-r3/system.sfs
```

などとして、init.sh内でコメントアウトされている下記のコメントを外す

```
# [ -d /proc/asound/card0 ] || modprobe snd-dummy
```

■確認したこと

1. カーネルモジュールの読み込み状況

   ```
   adb -s x.x.x.x:5555 shell 'su root lsmod'
   Module                  Size  Used by
   snd_dummy              13393  0 
   snd_pcm                90336  1 snd_dummy
   snd_timer              21404  1 snd_pcm
   snd                    67870  3 snd_dummy,snd_pcm,snd_timer
   soundcore               6811  1 snd
   binfmt_misc             9331  1 
   uvesafb                22118  2 
   cn                      4985  2 uvesafb
   btusb                  32289  0 
   btrtl                   4762  1 btusb
   btbcm                   7192  1 btusb
   btintel                 8579  1 btusb
   bluetooth             451936  4 btusb,btrtl,btbcm,btintel
   8250_fintek             2958  0 
   parport_pc             17448  0 
   parport                27029  1 parport_pc
   acpi_cpufreq           11129  0 
   pcspkr                  2222  0 
   psmouse               105313  0 
   atkbd                  17220  0 
   aesni_intel           159317  0 
   aes_x86_64              8043  1 aesni_intel
   i2c_piix4              11222  0 
   joydev                  9216  0 
   mac_hid                 3900  0 
   e1000                 113540  0
   ```
2. YouTubeアプリで適当な動画を再生し、「再生中に問題が発生しました」などと表示される
3. logcatで問題となっているようなメッセージ出力を確認

   ```
   02-01 11:57:15.954  1088  1088 W audio_hw_primary: Unable to find the mixer
   02-01 11:57:15.954  1088  1088 I AudioFlinger: loadHwModule() Loaded primary audio interface from Grouper audio HW HAL (audio) handle 1
   02-01 11:57:15.954  1088  1088 I AudioFlinger: openOutput(), module 1 Device 2, SamplingRate 48000, Format 0x000001, Channels 3, flags 2
   02-01 11:57:15.988  1088  1088 I AudioHwDevice: openOutputStream(), HAL returned sampleRate 48000, Format 0x1, channelMask 0x3, status -19
   02-01 11:57:15.989  1088  1088 W APM::AudioPolicyManager: Cannot open output stream for device 00000002 on hw module primary
   02-01 11:57:15.989  1088  1398 I AudioFlinger: AudioFlinger's thread 0xf4680000 ready to run
   02-01 11:57:16.009  1091  1091 I SamplingProfilerIntegration: Profiling disabled.
   02-01 11:57:16.034  1088  1088 I AudioFlinger: loadHwModule() Loaded a2dp audio interface from A2DP Bluez HW HAL (audio) handle 4
   02-01 11:57:16.037  1088  1088 I AudioFlinger: loadHwModule() Loaded usb audio interface from USB audio HW HAL (audio) handle 5
   02-01 11:57:16.037  1088  1088 W APM::AudioPolicyManager: Input device 00000002 unreachable
   02-01 11:57:16.037  1088  1088 E APM::AudioPolicyManager: Default device 00000002 is unreachable
   02-01 11:57:16.037  1088  1088 E APM::AudioPolicyManager: Failed to open primary output
   02-01 11:57:16.037  1088  1088 E APM::AudioPolicyEngine: getDeviceForStrategy() speaker device not found for STRATEGY_SONIFICATION
   02-01 11:57:16.037  1088  1088 E APM::AudioPolicyEngine: getDeviceForStrategy() speaker device not found for STRATEGY_SONIFICATION
   02-01 11:57:16.037  1088  1088 E APM::AudioPolicyEngine: getDeviceForStrategy() no device found for STRATEGY_TRANSMITTED_THROUGH_SPEAKER
   02-01 12:01:14.823  1088  1873 W APM::AudioPolicyManager: getOutput() could not find output for stream 1, samplingRate 0,format 0, channels 3, flags 0
   02-01 12:01:14.824  1088  1402 W APM::AudioPolicyManager: getOutput() could not find output for stream 1, samplingRate 0,format 0, channels 3, flags 0
   02-01 12:01:14.825  1088  1452 W APM::AudioPolicyManager: getOutput() could not find output for stream 1, samplingRate 44100,format 1, channels 3, flags 4
   02-01 12:01:14.825  1404  1451 E AudioTrack: Could not get audio output for session 9, stream type -1, usage 13, sample rate 44100, format 0x1, channel mask 0x3, flags 0x4
   02-01 12:01:14.825  1404  1451 E SoundPool: Error creating AudioTrack
   ```

Comment: PulseAudioをインストールする方法を回答しましたが、Androidに簡単にインストールする方法は無さそうですので、撤回しておきます。